# Convert simple HTML script to React

Tags: reactjs

I have a script to hide/show play buttons on 2 videos on 1 page that looks like this in HTML:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('demo').play();
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'none';
    });
    document.getElementById('demo').onended = function(){
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>

<div style="wrap">
    <img id="play" src="images/play.svg" />
    <video id="demo" src="images/demo.mp4" playsinline></video>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use it in React but the format doesn't seem to work:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import './Landing.scss';
import SmoothScroll from 'smooth-scroll'

function Landing() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add('landing')
    return () => document.body.classList.remove('landing')
  })
  
  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('demo').play();
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'none';
    });
    document.getElementById('demo').onended = function(){
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'block';
    }
  })

  return (
    <div className="Landing">
    
        <div className="wrap">
          <img id="play" src="play.svg" />
          <video id="demo" src="demo.mp4" playsInline />
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Landing
```

How do I format the useEffect part correctly?

Comment: Please show us your React code and be specific about the part you're having trouble with.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, please do attempt this on your own first and if you're stuck on a particular aspect or have an error or any other issue you struggle to overcome, *then* update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) alond with specific details on issue and any debugging steps taken.

Comment: @AndyRay added my React code, and the part I'm having trouble with — I've added script function using useEffect, but it doesn't work as it does in HTML version.

Comment: Ok, can you edit the question to include what "doesn't work" means? You'll also want to add an empty dependency array, `useEffect(() => { ... }, [])` to prevent the effect from running on every render.

Comment: @DrewReese sorry for that. Added more complete React code I'm trying to make work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to avoid querying the DOM as much as possible. In React you can access underlying DOMNodes via React refs. It is also preferred to attach event listeners directly to the elements.

```
function Landing() {
  const playRef = React.useRef();
  const demoRef = React.useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add('landing');
    return () => document.body.classList.remove('landing');
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency array so runs on mount only

  const clickHandler = () => {
    demoRef.current.play();
    playRef.current.style.display = 'none';
    
    demoRef.current.onended = function() {
      playRef.current.style.display = 'block';
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="Landing">
    
        <div className="wrap">
          <img
            ref={playRef}
            id="play"
            src="play.svg"
            onClick={clickHandler}
          />
          <video ref={demoRef} id="demo" src="demo.mp4" playsInline />
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code works perfectly everywhere except desktop Chrome for some strange reason.

Comment: @coachsteve Think you could create a *running*  codesandbox that reproduces the issue in Chrome that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: made it work by giving play buttons z-index:1. For some reason Chrome rendered them at -9999 by default. Thanks again!